# installed ubuntu 12.0 on employer but did not display unity desktop

Tags: 12.04

I installed ubuntu desktop 12.0 LTS on employer but did not display unity desktop.
I try to use 
sudo apt-get install unity

It said the unity had been the latest version.
Odes this mean hard problem?

Itonlydisplay terminal white/black text

I try unity --reset 
it said
Gconf Warning:client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon X11 initialisation failed

Comment: Please describe in detail what you are currently seeing - just the wallpaper?  A black screen?  How did you install ubuntu?

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: updated question

Comment: please add the hardware specs as requested.  Please state what you see during the boot process.  Are you seeing a black screen on logon?  Are you seeing a blackscreen after the GRUB boot screen?

Answer (score 0):

try `unity —reset` and `unity —replace` if this not help reinstall unity

Comment: unity –reset

WARNING: no DISPLAY variable set, setting it to :0

WARNING: Unity currently default profile, so switching to metacity while resetting the values

unity-panel-service: no process found

Comment: I try unity --reset it said

Comment: Gconf Warning:clinet failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon X11 initialisation failed

Comment: Try 

`sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity`